# Angular JS Data Load Limited?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been using AngularJS for a lot of small projects with rather small datasets. However, i have used it on a larger system that will continue to grow in size in terms of data. I am running into an exception now that seems to be related to the http response size. I'll do my best to explain the scenario and provide details below.

Total List: 1779 records(rather large object)
Working List:1717 records
Breaking List:1718 records

After reaching these results, i then ran the same code against the record that broke, 1718. This worked just fine when rendering just this record but when i included the other 1717 records, it once again broke. Leading me to believe my payload had grown to large. This page serves as a history of records thus it will continue to grow rapidly. Are there limitations to how much data Angular can process? My prior release not using Angular for this same page handles this load just fine so it seems Angular is the roadblock here.

Here is the below exception from Chrome console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at vc (angular.js:1272)
at ac (angular.js:9658)
at angular.js:9749
at n (angular.js:341)
at ed (angular.js:9748)
at c (angular.js:10521)
at angular.js:14991
at r.$eval (angular.js:16251)
at r.$digest (angular.js:16069)
```

Comment: what reason do you have for rendering 1718 records on a single page?  could you not use some sort of paging?

Comment: It is using a angular paging directive so there is paging being applied to only about 30 records to be displayed per page.

Comment: It seems like the server has sent an html isntead of JSON, the error points to an unexpected token `<` which ought to be from an html content not JSON. Also, really? 1779 records? Isn't it possible to paginate or something?

Comment: Even if you've added a paging directive, Angular still has to parse through all 1718 records. I would suggest implementing a "virtual" paging on the server side, so that it only returns 30 records at a time.

Comment: True...but i was right about angular not able to process this much data? It might be a safety mechanic built into it but not sure. The page still loads and operates within a second or two so performance hasn't been an issue. I can totally take another approach which reducing the dataset on server side makes the most sense.